# Dividing a Canvas into independent spaces

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there a way to separate a Canvas tag into several independent spaces so you could get en independent 2d context and independet coordenates for each.
For example if I wanted to have the same drawing twice I could divide the canvas in equal parts and use the same function in each part.

Comment: I can't control the html, only the javascript part so I can not have two canvases

Comment: `document.createElement("canvas");` you can create a new canvas using javascript

Comment: The best solution without changing visible HTML is to create two or more offscreen canvases and use them as intermediate textures. Perform all drawing to one or more of those, then draw those to the visible canvas. That also allows you to have tiled images by drawing to one offscreen canvas, then drawing that multiple times to the visible canvas.

Comment: I created a way to split a canvas into two according to any line. See [the related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51129170/2065702) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used what peachykeen sugested, created two offscreen canvases and then placed them as images in the original canvas, the code looks like:

```
canvas1 = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");

//Draw on the canvases

Drawing code

//Add them to the original canvas

if (OriginalCanvas && OriginalCanvas.getContext) {
    var context = OriginalCanvas.getContext('2d');
    if (context) {
        context.drawImage(canvas1, 0, 0, OriginalCanvas.width / 2, OriginalCanvas.height);
        context.drawImage(canvas2, OriginalCanvas.width / 2, 0, OriginalCanvas.width / 2, OriginalCanvas.height);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would not be difficult to mathematically create independent contexts within a single canvas.  For example say you have a 1000 x 500 canvas that you want to divide into two side-by-side 500 x 500 areas.  Make all your function calls take an "area" parameter and then use a simple calculation to adjust x-coordinates depending on the area you are working with.  Something like this:

```
function drawLine(fromX, fromY, toX, toY, area) {
    var startX = fromX + (area * 500);
    var startY = fromY;
    var endX = fromX + (area * 500);
    var endY = fromY;
    // draw your line here
}
```

In this case when working with the left area, you would use `area = 0` and `area = 1` for the right box.

Comment: For very simple applications, this does work. However, when you introduce anything that happens outside of providing raw coordinates  (stroke, scale, transform), you run into issues. The canvas won't prevent you from drawing outside of one section. Using an intermediate surface does, at a slight performance penalty.